# Why are my array objects are of type "type": ["object","null"] when generating a JsonSchema

Tags: c#, jsonschema

So, I have a class defined as such...

```
public class foo
{
    public List<bar> Bars {get;set;}
}

public class bar
{
    public string foorbar {get;set;}
}
```

When I use the `JsonSchemaGenerator` to generate its schema I get the following output...

```
var generator = new JsonSchemaGenerator();
return generator.Generate(typeof(foo), false);

{
  "type": "object",
  "properties" : {
      "Bars":{
          "type": "array",
          "items": {
              "type": ["object","null"],
              "properties": { 
                  "foorbar":{"type":"string"} 
              }
          }
      }
   }
}
```

So, why are my items inside the array of type **`"type": ["object","null"]`**

I believe this is causing issues, how can I remove the nullable object type here?

Thanks

Comment: I don't know what the second component is but it is an array of objects in JS, isn't it?

Comment: @Casey not sure what you mean by the second component... but my array of type bar is set to an array of type bar or null... I don't want it to be null-able...

Comment: I've updated my answer to be complete now that I know how to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scheme allows `null` because you could do something like this and try to serialize it, which is perfectly valid on the C# side:

```
myFoo.Bars.Add(null);
```

To disallow `null` values in JSON side of the array you need to use the `JsonArrayAttribute`.  Unfortunately this attribute can not be added to fields; it needs to be added to a class.  This means you will need to create a class that wraps the `List<bar>` and apply the attribute to that.  The final class structure looks like this:

```
public class foo
{
    public ListOfBar Bars { get; set; }
}

public class bar
{
    public string foorbar { get; set; }
}

[JsonArray(false)]
public class ListOfBar : List<bar> {}
```

Details on the attribute can be found [here](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonArrayAttribute.htm).

I was led to this attribute by looking at the [source code](https://github.com/pubnub/c-sharp/blob/master/monotouch/Newtonsoft.Json/Schema/JsonSchemaGenerator.cs) of `JsonSchemaGenerator`, specifically, line 285.

Comment: Thanks, looks promising.. Have you actually tried it? I get the following error..Attribute 'JsonArray' is not valid on this declaration type. It is only valid on 'class, interface' declarations.

Comment: I haven't had a chance to actually test it.  You may need to create a "special class" to wrap the `List` with that attribute and use that class instead of `List<Bar>`.

Comment: Something like `[JsonArray(false)] public class ListOfBar: List<Bar> {}`.  I'm actually opening Visual Studio now to do some testing, since this is more complicated than I originally thought.

Comment: Wouldn't it lead to less repetition to create a `NonNullableList<T>` or something?

Comment: @Casey That isn't a bad idea.  An even better solution would be if the `JsonArrayAttribute` could be used on fields, but I assume the authors have a good reason for not allowing it though.